# Problem with XslTransform

Tags: 2010, application-pages

I've tried to migrate an external application into Sharepoint using Application Pages. The external code is included as Class libraries that's installed into GAC when deploying. My application generates XML and transforms it using Xslt into XHTML so I tought I could use most of my code and tweak the xslt / javascript into generating XHTML that works in Sharepoint.

But I get a problem loading the Xslt file and I have no clue why. In my desperation I've given Everyone Full Control on the ASP.Net temp files directory at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files

The Errors I'm getting is:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   '0m_xtgin, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or
>   one of its dependencies. Failed to grant permission to execute.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131418) File name: '0m_xtgin,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' --->
>   System.Security.Policy.PolicyException: Execution permission cannot be
>   acquired.

The code where the problem occurs:

```
XslTransform Transformer = new XslTransform();
Transformer.Load(FolderName + FileName, new StyleResolver());
```

Any ideas what could be wrong or any ideas of what to do to work around this? What account could it be that's executing? Is it the Sharepoint App pool account?

Answer (score 0):

Is you assembly in the GAC or did you bin deploy it?

If it's a bin deploy, did you sign the assembly and configure the code access security?

Comment: All assemblies are in the GAC but the XslTransform seems to create dynamically generated assemblies from the xslt. I guess it's this generated assembly and some security permissions that creates the problem. The dynamically generated assembly is not in GAC (as far as I know).

Comment: That sounds weird.  I use the XslCompiledTransform a lot in SharePoint without this issue.  Mine are also in the gac.  Do you happen to be calling any extensions?  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's the deprecated XslTransform thats giving me the problem. I tried switching the XslTransform into XslCompiledTransform but it's not the same and I have no time rebuilding a the whole class. But maybe I have to :/